# Laravel Elixir - gulp watch does not trigger version()

Tags: laravel, gulp, gulp-watch, laravel-elixir

When I run `gulp` SASS is converted to CSS and saved to my public directory. Then they are versioned and work great. However, if I run `gulp watch` and update a SASS file, `.sass()` runs and copies a new .css file to public, but `.version()` is never called. How can I fix this?

**gulpfile.js**

```
var Elixir = require('laravel-elixir'),
    gulp = require('gulp');

Elixir(function (mix) {
  mix
    .sass('app.scss', 'public/assets/css/app.css')       
    .version('public/assets/css/app.css', 'public');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you cannot output your CSS to the same folder where you want your files versioned if you want to use gulp watch.

When I make either destination folder different, version() suddenly works again.